# nodemailer transport timing out with Google Gmail API

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, nodemailer

Excuse me if my terminology is off...I'm very new to web development and programming. I'm trying to develop a password reset page for my Node server. I set up a google project, enabled the Gmail API, and got client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, and refresh_token. I have triple checked that everything is entered correctly. I set up a transport script using nodemailer:

```js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
require("dotenv").config();

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN;
const REDIRECT_URI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground";

oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
});

async function sendmail() {
let accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: "gmail",
          auth: {
            type: "OAuth2",
            user: "example@example.com",
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
            accessToken: accessToken.token,
          },
          debug: true,
          logger: true,
        });
        let mailOptions = {
          to: result.email,
          from: "example@example.com",
          subject: "This is my subject",
          text: "Example test"
        };
        
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
          console.log("mail sent");
        });
 }
```

This isn't the entirety of the code, since I'm actually running this a routing function alongside MongoDB. However, everything seems to be fine, except my connection is timing out on the transport function with the following error code:

```html
[2022-01-09 20:56:08] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.7.2; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.7.2[client:6.7.2])
made it this far
[2022-01-09 20:56:08] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.2[client:6.7.2]
POST /forgotPass 200 11.313 ms - 1984
[2022-01-09 20:56:08] DEBUG [UVcfW8bbk4] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 209.85.201.108 [cache miss]
[2022-01-09 20:56:40] ERROR [UVcfW8bbk4] connect ETIMEDOUT 209.85.201.108:465
[2022-01-09 20:56:40] DEBUG [UVcfW8bbk4] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"
[2022-01-09 20:56:40] ERROR Send Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 209.85.201.108:465
```

What am I missing? I think I have tried everything...

Comment: And just fyi...I did disable two-factor authentication and allowed lesser secure apps.